# using a single method in two Models in Laravel; OOP PHP

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have 4 models held together by 4 pivot tables:

User, Company, Phone, Address

The User and Company are both tied together to Phone with the pivot tables user_phone and company_phone.

User has a method: `addDefaultPhone( Request $request )`.  It grabs `$request->input()` and creates a phone number and attaches it to the User.

The same exact method can be used in the Company class.  How can I include addDefaultAddress to both classes (without copying and pasting of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use inheritance or trait. Choose whatever you want.

## Inheritance

Create a base class:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ThingWithAPhone extends Model {
    public function addDefaultPhone() {
        /* Whatever you want... */
    }
}
```

Then both User and Company could extend this class:

```
// In the user file
class User extends ThingWithAPhone { /* ... */ }

// In the company file
class Company extends ThingWithAPhone { /* ... */ }
```

---

## Trait

Create a trait:

```
namespace App;

class Phonable {
    public function addDefaultPhone() {
        /* Whatever you want... */
    }
}
```

Use this trait:

```
// In the user file
class User extends Model { 
    use Phonable;
    /* ... */ 
}

// In the company file
class Company extends Model {         
    use Phonable;
    /* ... */ 
} }
```

With trait you can create class which have X traits, and one other class with Y traits and some of these traits may be common to both classes.

Comment: Seems to work.  What if I have two parent classes: ThingWithAPhone and ThingWithAnAddress?  How could I get a child class to use both of the parent classes?

Comment: Then you could use traits. I edited my answer to propose both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Best i can think of is to create a `trait` and share among the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The method uses $this->phone() which is either the relationship of User to Phone or Company to Phone, so I'm not sure if a Trait could work without passing both the User or Company object and the $request to it.  What do you think?

Comment: It will work you don't need to pass the object just use it